# Tensorflow: cifar10.py or cifar10_input.py does not work

Tags: tensorflow

If I try to use cifar10.py and cifar10_input.py in cifar10_train.py file,
it give below errors:

```
Filling queue with 20000 CIFAR images before starting to train. This will take a few minutes.

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc:25] Local device intra op parallelism threads: 4

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_session.cc:45] Local session inter op parallelism threads: 4

W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_ops.cc:114] Invalid argument: Signature mismatch, have: string_ref, float-> expected: string_ref, string->
```

and then terminal hangs...

I have only changed 2 things:

1. I replaced "from tensorflow.models.image.cifar10 import cifar10" by "import cifar10" and same for cifar10_input.py
2. Set max_steps to 5000, to check if the code runs without error.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.

There should be at least 2 input(.bin) files. I tried with one file before. E.g. There should be data_batch_1.bin and data_batch_2.bin. I tried with data_batch_1.bin before.